# Button moves page down slightly on hover

Tags: html, css

I've added a hover effect to a button - it pushes the page down slightly when I hover over the button. Can't figure out why it's doing that, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```css
.button_aboutme {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #0071e3;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 130px;
}

.button_aboutme a {
  color: #FFF;
}

.button_aboutme:hover {
  border: solid #0071e3;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.button_aboutme:hover a {
  color: #0071e3;
}
```

```html
<div class="button_aboutme">
  <a href="about.html" title="Contact Page">About me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: is the small amount equal to border-bottom + border-top for your button?

Comment: Add `border: solid transparent;` to `.button_aboutme`. A border adds to the total width/height of an element, hence the shift as the unhovered element has no border where `:hover` has a border. Adding a transparent border hides that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The button is "moving" and "changing" it size, because it has "border" only on "hover" mode.
You can add `border: solid transparent;` to `.button_aboutme` so button will have the same border both on `.button_aboutme` and `.button_aboutme` with `hover`.

Note:

you can set it to some other color (Let's say "#00ff00) to see the border without the hover state, it is easier to understand it like that.

```css
      .button_aboutme {
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        background-color: #0071e3;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 200px;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 130px;
        /* border: solid 3px #00ff00; */
        border: solid transparent;
      }

      .button_aboutme a {
        color: #fff;
      }

      .button_aboutme:hover {
        border: solid #0071e3;
        background-color: #fff;
        transition: 0.1s;
      }

      .button_aboutme:hover a {
        color: #0071e3;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="button_aboutme">
      <a href="about.html" title="Contact Page">About me</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a transparent border, you can also use the `outline` property. The good thing about that is when it's applied it does not interfere with the rest of the document flow so applying it won't reposition any other elements. It's really handy when you want to add a 'border' around a div or other element to find out what's going on during debugging without affecting any other part of the document.

References: Outline on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) and [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/outline/)

```css
.button_aboutme {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #0071e3;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 130px;
}

.button_aboutme a {
  color: #FFF;
}

.button_aboutme:hover {
  /*border: solid #0071e3; removed this */
  outline: solid #0071e3; /* added this */
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.button_aboutme:hover a {
  color: #0071e3;
}
```

```html
<div class="button_aboutme">
  <a href="about.html" title="Contact Page">About me</a>
</div>
```